# BufferedReader not returning all lines from ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\file\\ffmpeg.exe", "-i", src);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
try {
   while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(br.readLine() + "\n");
   }
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now this is outputting:

> built on Mar 22 2013 08:56:38 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
>
> libavutil      52. 22.101 / 52. 22.101
>
> libavformat    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
>
> libavfilter     3. 48.100 /  3. 48.100
>
> libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
>
> Input #0, avi, from 'C:\Users\Olle\Desktop\file.avi':
>
> encoder         : Lavf52.104.0
>
> Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (DX50 / 0x30355844), yuv420p, 720x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR 30:17], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn,
>   30001 tbc
>
> At least one output file must be specified

When it should output MUCH more (In Regular commandline MUCH more is outputed).

I don't understand what is going on. The weird thing is that when I compile the above code on Mac, it works fine. It's only in Windows I have this issue.

Even with:

```
String line = null;                     
try {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = br.readLine() + "\n";                            
    }
```

Same issue...

Comment: That's just the response of FFMPEG when doing -i file.avi. Not related to this issue.

Comment: No \\ but / under windows is more portable: `ProcessBuilder( "C:/file/ffmpeg.exe", "-i", src );` and `System.out.println( br.readLine());` may be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with the br.readLine() in the while you skip every second line!

the code should be

```
String line = null; 
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   System.out.println(line + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Just changed it, same issue! :/

Answer (score 2):

By making 2 calls to br.readLine() you can skipping one line. You need to assign value of br.readLine() to a string and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the answer the output of your command?

```
At least one output file must be specified
```

According to this, you need to specify an output file as well.

Comment: This is part of the output of FFMPEG and not related to the problem.